# What to do when seeing this error: the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I am running a docker machine and phpinfo() shows Mongodb extension as enabled.

When I run:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

From my local machine, I see this error message:

> mongodb/mongodb 1.7.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8 -> the requested PHP
> extension mongodb is missing from your system.

**Additional information:** when I SSH the docker container and executed this command:

```
php -i | grep -C4 -i "mongodb.*version"
```

I get back MongoDB extension version => 1.8.1

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you running the composer commands within SSH?

Comment: No, I am running composer from my local Mac machine.

Comment: There's your problem. The composer command in the Mac terminal does not know about the PHP extensions enabled in the docker container. Run the composer command in the docker, and it should work.

Comment: You can also use composer locally with the --ignore-platform-dependencies flags. I use it all the time to install the libraries on my local machine for programming and static analysis while using the docker runtime for actual development.

Comment: Regarding your next question: read the output carefully. You have conflicting dependencies. If you can, update illuminate/bus to a newer version. But the real culprit might be another package. Make sure they are all up to date

Comment: Please open two seperate questions if you have two questions. Also, always add your attempts to resolve the errors

Comment: @Transitive Thank you! This solved the issue.
Very helpful and solved the issue, I will open a new question as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the dependencies installed in docker, just not on your local machine.
If you want to install the dependencies also locally, you will have to either install the extension yourself or run the composer command with the --ignore-platform-reqs flag to get rid of the error.

Comment: Please note I used "--ignore-platform-reqs" instead "--ignore-platform-dependencies", since the latest resolved in The "--ignore-platform-dependencies" option does not exist.